# How to get selected values objects from multi select control

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack, mean.io

I have a select box like this

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : submitted && form.options.$invalid }">
    <label for="options">Options</label>
    <select multiple class="form-control" name="options" id="options" ng-model="form.options" data-ng-options="option._id as option.name for option in availableOptions" required>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="submitted && form.options.$invalid" class="help-block">
      <p ng-show="form.options.$error.required">Please select options</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the values of options is like below

```
var options = [
    {
        '_id': option1_id,
        'name': option1_name,
        'value': option1_value
    },
    {
        '_id': option2_id,
        'name': option2_name,
        'value': option2_value
    },
    {
        '_id': option3_id,
        'name': option3_name,
        'value': option3_value
    }
];
```

How can I get the full objects of selected values in angularJS?

Answer (score 0):

> angularFilter

```
  .filter('findobj', function () {
     return function (dataobj, category1) {
         if (!category1) return dataobj;

       return dataobj.filter(function (options) {
         return options.name == category1 ;

       });
      }
    })
```

Here u can find this solution: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6jmx8se/1/)

or u can go through this solution also [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cuvuzd8/2/)

> I hope this will help

Comment: @Dau u can accept the answer if this is what ur looking for